# Should I use the Vulkan loader?

Tags: vulkan

According to the vulkan sdk documentation under the subtopic "Application Interface to the Loader" the best performance way to setup Vulkan interface is

https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.0.57.0/windows/LoaderAndLayerInterface.html#user-content-best-application-performance-setup

But I don't know how to actually implement this or if there is a library that already does this.

As a sidenote if I choose to use the loader library where is the list of all non-core non-wsi functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the loader, there's almost never a good reason not to. The easiest route is to link against the loader library, but if your app might need to run on systems that don't have a Vulkan driver installed (even if it only needs to run just enough to show an error message) then you should load the loader library dynamically.

Even when you're using the loader, you can get the same performance as if you didn't use it, by calling functions obtained via vkGetDeviceProcAddr. When you do that, you're calling directly into the driver, there is literally zero overhead from the loader.

All available extensions are in vulkan.h. Extension commands (functions) are sorted by the extension that provides them, so it's easy to tell which extension you need for a particular command. You can also look at the [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#extensions); each extension is listed in the appendix, with the list of structures and commands it adds.

Comment: So if a function has already been defined by the loader how do I use vkGetDeviceProcAddr to overload the old definition from the loader

Comment: Somewhere, either as a global, member of a struct, etc. you declare a function pointer for the function: "PFN_vkCmdDraw MyCmdDraw;". After creating the device, set it by calling vkGetDeviceProcAddr. Then call it: "MyCmdDraw(commandBuffer, ...);"

Comment: But if I wanna use the Vulkan.hpp file the vk::Device member function calls the regular prototype for drawing.

Also are these good canidate functions for using vkGetDeviceProcAddr:

vkMapMemory, vkUnMapMemory, vkAcquireNextImageKHR, vkQueueSubmit,  vkQueuePresentKHR,  vkQueueWaitIdle, vkCmdDrawIndexed

Comment: Yes, that is a limitation of vulkan.hpp: it doesn't provide a way to use per-device function pointers.

Comment: Is vkCmdDrawIndexed viable for being called by vkGetDeviceProcAddr

Comment: Yes, any command where the first parameter is VkDevice, or an object that is a child (or grand-child, etc.) of a VkDevice. VkCmdDrawIndexed takes a VkCommandBuffer, which is allocated from a VkCommandPool, which is created from a VkDevice.

Comment: By loader do You mean vulkan-1.dll or libvulkan.so.1 libraries? As far as I know it's the only (reasonable and standarized) way of using Vulkan. The only other way I'm aware of is using the driver libraries directly, which doesn't make sense because each vendor or even driver version has it's own, different library.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [first part](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/api-without-secrets-introduction-to-vulkan-part-1) of Intel's tutorial or [code samples](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Vulkan-Cookbook/tree/master/Library/Source%20Files/01%20Instance%20and%20Devices) from the Vulkan Cookbook. They contain information about how to connect with Vulkan library and how to dynamically load function pointers.

As for the list of extensions - do You need all of them? Enabling all released instance and device extensions isn't probably a good idea because it drastically limits devices on which Your code will run. Just select extensions You need for Your project, enable them during instance and/or device creation and (if necessary) load their functions using the code available in the links provided above.

Comment: I know I don't need all the extensions I meant just to find the ones I will need in an easier format rather than just looking at vulkan.h

Comment: Official spec has a version in which all released extensions are listed and explained.